# Angular UI tinymce errors cannot call method add of undefined

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

EDIT

If it helps the code that it errors at is

```
// Update model when calling setContent (such as from the source editor popup)
          setup: function (ed) {
            ed.onSetContent.add(function (ed, o) {   <----Right Here ed is undefined
              if (ed.isDirty()) {
                ed.save();
                ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                if (!scope.$$phase)
                  scope.$apply();
```

I'm trying to get a working example of tinymce ported through angular-ui but I keep getting the following error on line 1225 of angular-ui

Cannot call method add of undefined.  I just updated my build of angular-ui so I know it's up to date.

I'm calling my scripts in this order

bootstrap css
jquery ui css
angular-ui css

jquery script

jquery ui script

tiny mce

tiny mce jquery port

angular js

angular ui.js

app.js

controller.js

directives.js

My HTML looks like this

```
<body ng-app="tinymce">
<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="tinymce"></textarea>
<body>
```

and I pass the ui dependecy like so

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('tinymce', ['ui']);
```

I don't know what else to do.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem? I don't know if you're using the wrong version of TinyMCE, and there is not enough information here to go on.

Comment: Same issue with me, have you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem, If you are installing using bower, you might be installing tinymce-release 4.0.2. I just found that that version is not working.

Using bower, the last available version is 3.5.8. I've simple change the version tinymce-release and now it works

Comment: That was my issue as well

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have not updated Bower with the latest code from github. If you copy this into your components folder it will work:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js

Answer (score 0):

"use strict";
var app = angular.module('tinymce', ['ui.tinymce']);